# Golang: Enforcing strictly comparable during compile time

Tags: go

I stumbled upon this excellent article [All your comparable types](https://go.dev/blog/comparable) talking about the language spec changes to accommodate the new `comparable` type constraint.

In the end of the article, in the **Consequences and remedies** section, Robert mentioned a way to assert, during compile time, strictly comparable types:

```
type T struct { … }

// isComparable may be instantiated with any type that supports ==
// including types that are not strictly comparable because of the
// exception for constraint satisfaction.
func isComparable[_ comparable]() {}

func _[P T]() {
_ = isComparable[P] // P supports == only if T is strictly comparable
}
```

without giving a good explanation of why this works.

Can anyone explain this comment `P supports == only if T is strictly comparable` step by step referencing the language spec?

As far as I understood it, `[P T]` is saying `P` has to satisfy the type set specified by `interface{T}`, but this set only contains one type which is `T`. Also `T` is comparable, meaning that `T` supports the `==` operator. Then shouldn't `P` also support `==` operator as well? Why does the comment say `P supports == only if T is strictly comparable`?